# Help with framing around old basement stairway

Tags: framing

I know this is always a tough question, but just looking for any insight. We are working on a bathroom reno in our basement and it happens to be where an old set of stairs came down to the basement. We can only see three sides of the old stair opening. The joists and one header, that we can, are doubled up. There is blocking bridging the 32" old opening. The current closet wall runs perpendicular to this blocking, but we will be moving the wall to the other side of the double joists. Therefore, the blocking won't be running over the wall any longer.

The question is, would moving the wall be of any concern since I would think those blocking aren't supposed to carry weight? Above this area is a coat closet and kitchen pantry as well. If any other info would help, please let me know!

Here is the wall that is moving. Basically where the right side of the door is would be the header for the old stairs.
[image]

The black lines are the double joists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please replace the seconf photo with something less confusing. what s the other blue line?  the left wall is a confusing mess of stains and ininite studs. perhaps use two pictures.

Comment: The blue lines are the current walls. The yellow is the opening of the closet door. Left of the yellow line is the ceiling in the current bedroom. The I drew in the black lines fro the joists.

Comment: Can you orient the 2nd pic for us? You've labeled a part "foundation" - to me, that's means this is the bottom (floor), and the pic is vertical working up to the ceiling, but that makes zero sense that there would be "horizontal studs". Tell us where you were standing and which direction (up/down, left right) the camera was facing when you took that pic.

Comment: that looks much more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The current wall doesn't look at all structural, so removing it should not cause any structural problems.